# Renderning simple square in Android OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Here are my coordinates to draw a square:

```
static float vertices_textures[] = {
    //vertices            //positions
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};
Buffer vertices_textures_buffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(vertices_textures);
```

Then my initialization code is:

```
    egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
    eglDisplay = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if (eglDisplay == EGL10.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
        throw new RuntimeException("eglGetDisplay failed");
    }

    int[] version = new int[2];
    if (!egl.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("eglInitialize failed");
    }

    EGLConfig eglConfig = chooseEglConfig();
    eglContext = createContext(egl, eglDisplay, eglConfig);

    eglSurface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, surfaceTexture, null);

    if (eglSurface == null || eglSurface == EGL10.EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
        throw new RuntimeException("GL Error: " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl.eglGetError()));
    }

    if (!egl.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("GL make current error: " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl.eglGetError()));
    }
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, OrwellShaders.Vertex.video);
    int fragmentShader = loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, OrwellShaders.Fragment.color);

    program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

    glLinkProgram(program);

    vertexInLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, "aPos");
    textureInLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, "aTexCoord");

    glGenVertexArrays(1, vertexArrayObject, 0);
    glGenBuffers(1, vertexBufferObject, 0);
    glGenBuffers(3, pixelBufferObjects, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject[0]);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_textures.length, vertices_textures_buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexInLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 5*4 , 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexInLocation);

    glVertexAttribPointer(textureInLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 5*4 , 3*4);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureInLocation);
```

This is how I render:

```
    glUseProgram(program);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 1f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject[0]);

    glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, GLES11Ext.GL_RGBA8_OES, 100, 100,
            0, GLES11Ext.GL_RGBA8_OES, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Here is the EGL context creation

```
    private EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay eglDisplay, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
    int[] attribList = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3, EGL10.EGL_NONE};
    return egl.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attribList);
}

private EGLConfig chooseEglConfig() {
    int[] configsCount = new int[1];
    EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
    int[] configSpec = getConfig();

    if (!egl.eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, configSpec, configs, 1, configsCount)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to choose config: " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(egl.eglGetError()));
    } else if (configsCount[0] > 0) {
        return configs[0];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here are my shaders

```
public static final String vertex  = 
        "#version 320 es\n " +
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n " +
        "layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;\n " +
        "\n " +
        "out vec2 TexCoord;\n " +
        "\n " +
        "void main()\n " +
        "{\n " +
        "    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n " +
        "    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);\n " +
        "}\n";
```

and

```
    public static final String color  = 
        "#version 320 es\n " +
        "precision mediump float;\n " +
        "in vec2 TexCoord;\n " +
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n " +
        "\n " +
        "void main()\n " +
        "{\n " +
        "    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);\n " +
        "}\n";
```

As you can see by the shader I should see a red square, but I see a lot of random pixels binking on the screen. If I use glClearColor, I can see the color I put there, but nothing more happens.

Is there something wrong with my vertex arrays?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using

```
import static android.opengl.GLES32.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

The 4th respectively 5th parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) have to be the stride between consecutive attributes respectively the offset to the first component **in bytes** rather than the number of elements.
Size the size of a `float` element is 4, it has to be:

```java
glVertexAttribPointer(vextexInLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 5*4, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vextexInLocation);

glVertexAttribPointer(textureInLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 5*4, 3*4);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureInLocation);
```

Comment: Even if I'm using a ByteBuffeer? See that I pass vertices_textures_buffer to glBufferData

Comment: @LucasZanella Yes even then, because the stride is not 5 bytes, it is 5 floats which are 20 bytes. The size of a single `float` in the byte buffer are still 4 bytes

Comment: I used the suggested additions but it still wont work. I updated the code and added EGL initialization. Can you see anything wrong? (I also changed my buffers like `vertexArrayObject` to `int[]` (was `IntBuffer` before). Are the initializations rigth?